# TypeScript | Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'ICustomRequest'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm migrating a existing project to it. I created a file called yelp-camp.d.ts:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv {
    MONGO_URI: string;
    GOOGLE_API: string;
    SECRET_KEY: string;
  }
}

declare namespace Express {
  export interface ICustomRequestUser extends Express.User{
    _id: string;
    username: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
  }
  export interface ICustomRequest<T> extends Express.Request {
    body: T;
    params: {
      id: string;
      comment_id: string;
    };
  }
}
```

And on my controllers I use this ICustomRequest interface, like this:

```
async create(req: Express.ICustomRequest<ICampground>, res: Response) {
    try {
      const data = await this.geocoder.geocode(req.body.location);

      const imageUrl = await upload(req.file);

      const newCampground = {
        name: req.body.name,
        image: imageUrl,
        description: req.body.description,
        author: {
          id: req.user!._id,
          username: req.user!.username,
        },
        price: req.body.price,
        location: data[0].formattedAddress!,
        lat: data[0].latitude!,
        lng: data[0].longitude!,
      };

      await CampgroundModel.create(newCampground);

      return res.status(201).json(newCampground);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      return res.status(401).json({});
    }
  }
```

However I'm getting this error: Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'ICustomRequest'. How can I solve this?

Comment: I have a feeling you have left something out (perhaps you have an `import` in `yelp-camp.d.ts`). However, what you are doing makes no sense and is a bad practice. If you are defining types to annotate your own application, don't attempt to add them to declarations for existing libraries.

Comment: No imports on my yelp-camp.d.ts... What would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: It was just a guess since there's a common scoping mistake. Anyway, `ICustomRequest` is _your_ type. Do not add it to the `Express` global namespace - use it directly.

Comment: But I need to extends the Request, so this is normal, right? Without implementing a namespace. And, I tried to create my namespace and extends the Express.User and Express.Request, but gives me the same error.

Comment: No, it is not normal. You are saying that the extending type must reside in the same scope as the type extended. What would lead you to believe that?

Comment: So, I'll use the request param, the default type is Express.Request. But I need to add some custom props on this type. For that, I create a type that extends Express.Request and holds my own props. Yes, I understand that redeclaring the same namespace is wrong but if I only create My interface that extends Express.Request?

Comment: What I am saying is the following: create a module like `custom-request.ts` containing `export interface CustomRequest extends Express.Request {}`. Then, in the module containing your controller, add `import {CustomeRequest} from './custom-request';`

Comment: Is exactly what I tried to explain. I will do it! But if I want to create my namespace, what would be the right way?

Comment: Let me know if you get it working. BTW, I had a typo: missing `from`

Comment: Okay, this worked like a charm! Thank you!